# Skype for iPhone image/link preview

Tags: malware, phishing, skype, image

Today a Skype contact of mine sent me a link in the chat. This link I believe was sent without the person knowing it, and it contains a reference in the URL to my Skype ID, in the form ...tumblr...#my_skype_id

Unfortunately the iphone (up to date) Skype app by default creates a preview of the link, in this case it showed me an image below the link, even though I didn't click on anything of course.

I understand the app may have some sort of built-in protection for this sort of things (or at least I hope), but still is it likely that I've been compromised? Besides changing a bunch of passwords, is there anything else I should worry about?

Comment: Did you find any **non-public** information relating to you  in the URL? At the moment, this doesn't quite look like you've been compromised.

Comment: @Krazor No, I didn't. I also looked it up using urlquery.net but it didn't give any info, just remained in queued status forever.

Comment: This rather seems to be a sort of tracking-/ advertising URL in my opinion. Retrieving resources from untrusted URLs (even though you did not actually do it yourself) can always include malware. Is the server, on which the resource is located, a trusted and/or well-known one? I think you'll be on the safe side for now, but changing your passwords is a good habit anyways.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve that info, but unfortunately I previously deleted chat history and app. If I remember correctly, it was something like ...blitchly...tumblr..., where the dots are missing characters.